# ODI master repository dropped

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

By mistake the ODI master repository schema has got dropped and now I dont see any of the work which was done in ODI studio. My work repository is still intact. Is there anyway I can get all my work back by creating the same master repository and link with my work repository. There is 2 months of development work which I don't want to lose just because master repository is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a production instance of ODI, I guess the DBA has daily backups of the database and can restore the schema holding your master repository. Or there might be some regular exports of the repository in XML files.

Otherwise, you can try creating a new one and recreate a similar topology and security model. You will need to reattach the work repository to it : https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/administer-develop/admin_reps.htm#ODIAD163

Then go in the model pane of the designer and make sure all the models are linked to a logical schema.